Escapes the Function Body Here
I have the following code:
    use tonic::metadata::MetadataMap;

    fn insert_metadata(
       metadata: &mut MetadataMap,
       key: &str,
       value: String,
       ) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
       match MetadataValue::try_from(value) {
          Ok(v) => {
            metadata.insert(key, v);
            Ok(())
        }
        Err(_) => Err("Invalid metadata value"),
    }
}

But I get a compile error that I don't understand.  I have tried Googling but not been able to find anything useful.  Here is the error:
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
   --> src/service.rs:150:13
    |
145 |     key: &str,
    |     ---  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
    |     |
    |     `key` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
...
150 |             metadata.insert(key, v);
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |             |
    |             `key` escapes the function body here
    |             argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`


What's MetadataMap? You probably need to convert the key into an owned String.

It looks from the error that metadata.insert expects key to be a &'static str, but it is not marked 'static. Hard to tell for certain without a [mre] though.

Updated the example.

This is exactly the same problem as in the linked question, just the traits and structs have different names. The solution is also the same, use the corresponding MetadataKey::from_bytes
